# How to easily combine data sets; how to quantify text data

Tags: r

I'm just getting started with R and R-Studio.  I'm working with a couple different data sets: each contains the same variables, and within those variables the same types of information.

The data sets have been imported into R-Studio as separate sets/files.  First question: how can I go about combining them?  There are seventeen in all.  Here is an abbreviated example of two of them:

```
   EVENT_ID         STATE YEAR MONTH_NAME     EVENT_TYPE INJURIES_DIRECT DEATHS_DIRECT
1    5551758 MASSACHUSETTS 1996  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
2    5551581 MASSACHUSETTS 1996  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
3    5551757 MASSACHUSETTS 1996  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
4    5551573 MASSACHUSETTS 1996  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
5    5551572 MASSACHUSETTS 1996  January       Heavy Snow               0             0

    EVENT_ID         STATE YEAR MONTH_NAME     EVENT_TYPE INJURIES_DIRECT DEATHS_DIRECT
1    5591809 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January   Winter Weather               0             0
2    5591810 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January   Winter Weather               0             0
3    5591817 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
4    5591820 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
5    5591819 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
6    5591811 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
7    5591813 MASSACHUSETTS 1997  January       Heavy Snow               0             0
```

As you can see, each has the same headers.  Once I have combined these data sets - to not include the headers in the middle of the data! - I will begin analysis.  Second question: how can I go about quantifying factors, such as those found in the EVENT_TYPE variable?  I tried converting them to "as.numeric", which I believe orders them 1-x based on alphabetical order.  That's fine, but how would I go about keeping track of that data?  I'm hoping to play with them like I would numeric data, but do not know where or how to begin doing that.

If there is another place this is explained, please let me know and I'm happy to read those examples.  I wasn't sure how to best ask.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list and run rbind on them with do.call:

```
  do.call( rbind,  list(df1,df2,df3, ....,dfN) )
```

Answer (score 1):

For the actual unification: see BondedDust's answer (for a more expansive thing to achieve basically the same end, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902411/merging-df-1-df-2-df-3-df-x-into-one-dataframe/22902548#22902548).)

In terms of ordering and ranking the EVENT_TYPE quantitative elements; have you looked at ?as.factor() at all? If you could explain what you're looking to do with the data we'll probably be able to provide a more substantive answer :).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had not looked at as.factor() yet.  I'm actually looking to discover what is possible to do with this data: I would like to find a way to discover whether winter is increasingly getting worse in MA (i.e., are there an increasing number of EVENT_TYPEs).

Comment: as.factor might be worth investigating, then; it assigns ranked, numeric identifiers to each unique variable in the column. The disadvantage, though, is that this is 'which one appears first' and not the severity of the event. I would suggest simply substituting the string EVENT_TYPE values for actual numeric values, if you're looking to weight them.

Answer (score 1):

`help(rbind)` will get you started.

You want to read the data in as datafames, probably using `read.csv` or `read.table`, then combine the dataframes with `rbind`.
See `help(data.frame)` and `help(rbind)` for explanations and examples. There's also a very brief example at http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/rbind.php

Don't convert the strings to factors until after you combine them. You can do this by specifying `strings.as.factors = False` when you load the data.

Once you have the dataframes combined, though, you can use `d[,colnum] = as.factor(d[,colnum])` to convert the column to a factor. This will create integer levels for each of the phrases that appear in that column. You may want to specify the order of the factors to use if you want to actually work with them numerically (so that heavy snow has a higher number than snow, etc.). You will also need to check for missing values, and watch out for variations in the factors such as upper case/lower case or extra spaces.

Comment: Thank you, Suz.  This is extremely helpful.  I'm receiving errors on the final part of your suggestion: there are three columns/variables I want to convert to factors - which I believe will eventually allow me to work with them? - but each time I run your suggestion above, I keep getting an error that says "Error...object X not found".  Any tips?

Comment: Ooops. That's what I get for writing R code from memory. It should be fixed now. (mind the `,` in `d[,colnum]`). You can always check the state of your data with `summary(d)`. It will show which columns are character and which are numeric or factor.