# R rbind data.tables with different column using do.call on vector of names

Tags: r, data.table, do.call

I have several data.tables with different columns that I would like to append/rowbind. The outcome should be a data.table with all columns (not only columns appearing all of the rbinded dataset). Here is an example

```
library(data.table)
df1 = data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
df2 = data.frame(a = c(11:15), b = c(16:20), c = LETTERS[1:5])
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)
```

borrowed from @kdauria's answer in this post [Combine two data frames by rows (rbind) when they have different sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns?rq=1).

But I only know my datasets as a vector of names c("a","b") because they vary from occasion to occasion. Because of that I am doing the following

```
goo <- function(...) rbind(...,fill=TRUE)
do.call(goo,sapply(c("a","b"),function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
```

which gets the job done, but I am thinking whether there is not a more clever way construct the do.call() call.

Comment: Related: [list data.tables in memory and combine by row (rbind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373307/list-data-tables-in-memory-and-bind-them); [Combine several data frames in the global environment by row (rbind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902411/combine-several-data-frames-in-the-global-environment-by-row-rbind)

Comment: The "duplicate" does not take into consideration that the data tables have different columns (just to make it clear for potential future users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mget()`:

```
a = data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10))
b = data.frame(a = c(11:15), b = c(16:20), c = LETTERS[1:5])
vn <- c("a","b")

rbindlist(mget(vn), fill = TRUE)

#      a  b    c
#  1:  1  6 <NA>
#  2:  2  7 <NA>
#  3:  3  8 <NA>
#  4:  4  9 <NA>
#  5:  5 10 <NA>
#  6: 11 16    A
#  7: 12 17    B
#  8: 13 18    C
#  9: 14 19    D
# 10: 15 20    E
```